# Spark on Kubernetes troubleshooting

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, scheduler, spark-operator

I have a kubernetes cluster where I try to run a spark example application (spark-pi).

I have setup a service account = `spark`

**Scenario**

When I do a `spark-submit` from the command line like below, I am getting a container error.

```
bin/spark-submit --master k8s://https://IP:port --deploy-mode cluster --name spark-pi --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --conf spark.executor.instances=2 --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=spark:latest --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=Never --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 10
```

**Expectation:**

Get the value of `pi` = `3.14` printed in the logs

**Actual result:**

The driver pod is not coming up due to an error scenario.
when I do a describe on the pod, I see the below:

- `$ kubectl describe pods spark-pi-driver`

```
"applicationState": {
    "state": "FAILING",
    "errorMessage": "driver container failed with ExitCode: 1, Reason: Error"
  },
```

Events:none

I don't see any events as well

Is there a better way to troubleshoot this scenario ? Please help.